# To round the value

Tags: data-binding

I am doing addition of float values and storing it in database .The sum is getting calculated as 2.222222248E4 but it should be 2222222248.4

Comment: As @Bad Display Name says, they are identical, it's just how it is being displayed to you. Are you trying to print the value out / display it to a user?

Comment: I know thae value of both is same but i want to store the actual value which doesnt contains E in the value

Answer (score 1):

First off, `2.222222248e4` does *not* equal `2222222248.4`, it equals `22222.222484`. `Ne4` means `N x 104` which simply shifts the decimal four places to the right.

Secondly, assuming that was a typo and the two values you have *are* identical, this is a presentation issue, not a data issue.

The thing in the database (assuming you're storing it as a floating point value of some sort and not some weird string) doesn't care one bit about presentation, databases are for storing data. It's the way you select the value *out* of the database that decides how it's formatted.

This depends entirely on what you're using to get the value out (which you haven't really specified). For example, DB2 would allow you to use:

```
select cast (float_column as decimal (5,2))
```

to format the number something like `999.99`.